# Create PPT like slide show in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window, powerpoint, slideshow

I have a requirement where I have to code Powerpoint to access data from sql server and display in tabular and graphical manner. Instead of doing it in VBA (as i'm weak in VBA) I would prefer to go with WPF Window application in C#.

My question is, Is that possible to create Powerpoint presentation like slide show in WPF where on every slide there will be graph and datagrid and marquee text show updated data from database. Any suggestion or links highly appreciated.

So far What I've found:

1) If I make my windowstyle to none and state to maximized. it will appear in full screen window.

```
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

2) and on Each window by using dockpanel I can arrange controls like datagrid on leftside and graph on right side and in bottom marquee text.

3) Using timer switching between each windows.

with these I might be able to achieve what I'm looking for but is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really useful library that you can use for this purpose. It features many different transitions, just like PowerPoint and is really easy to use. It is called 'Transitionals' and you can download it from the CodePlex website:

[Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/)

UPDATE >>>

This `Transitionals` library is now on version 1.2, but you can download the help file for version 1.0 by clicking on the 'TransitionalsHelp_1_0.zip' link on [this page](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/releases/view/12954) on CodePlex.

Comment: Thank you sheridan, Is that possible to get sample application related to this Transitionals.